# rails: form_for(@object) implies path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using nested resources for the first time Had to adjust all paths in views but now I find I have to adjust objects for form_for(@object) because the objects imply paths Is this one of the reasons form_for is being depracated?

Comment: What do you mean by "objects imply paths", exactly?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev polymorphic routing?

Comment: The @object actually represents a route to rails Make a mistake and rails will complain no such route was found, that's how I know

Answer (score 1):

### No

The reason `form_for` is being depreachiated is that `form_with` replaces both `form_for` and `form_tag` which basically did similiar jobs but had completly different signatures.

`form_with` can handle both the cases where are form is bound to a object through the model option or where there is no object and yields a form builder object which `form_tag` didn't do. Unlike `form_tag` you don't need to use the low level input helpers which have a really clunky interface.

We will probally se more similiar changes in the future when [older methods with insane signatures](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) get replaced with more modern equivilents that take keyword arguments.

The behavior of looking up routes with the polymorphic routes helpers is still there when you use `form_with(model: @thing)` which will use `@thing.to_model.model_name.param_key` to guess that there is route helper named `things_path` or `thing_path`. This behavior is very much in line with the convention over configuration approach of Rails and is unlikely to go away.

Comment: form_with<what?> for an inner nested route? If I have resources comments nested under resources posts in my routes then the route for comment is new_post_comment so how should I use form_with in that case?

Comment: `form_with(model: [post, comment])`. This is really no different then `form_for` as both just pass the arguments to [ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html).

Comment: Can you try testing that It gets me an error

Comment: Heh I figured it out by reading I'll answer my question instead of posting the solution as a comment

Answer (score 1):

This works:
<%= form_with(model: @post, url: [@post, @comment]) do |f| %>